# Messed up with my ssh_config file. How can I recover the original file?

Tags: ssh, configuration, openssh

I was setting up ssh on Ubuntu.

I accidentally copied the contents of `sshd_config` in `ssh_config` file! 
Is there a place where I can find the original one? Fortunately I didn't touch the `ssh_config`. I just set up `sshd_config`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the file from the OpenSSH client package:

```
apt-get download openssh-client
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile openssh-client_*.deb | sudo tar -xC / ./etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

This will extract the `ssh_config` from that package directly to its destined location `/etc/ssh/`.