# Sudo: sessions still open not unmounting

Tags: 14.04, sudo, privileges, su

Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04 is running on my computer.

By mistake the sudoers file on my computer was edited and now looks like this:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

root        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And I'm logged in as a simple user. When I run `sudo`, I get `Sessions still open, not unmounting`. What can I do to recover the previous `/etc/sudoers` file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting one of [my previous answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/621960/158442), get the file from the `sudo` package:

```
apt-get download sudo
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile sudo_*.deb | pkexec tar -xC / ./etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Use `pkexec` instead of `sudo` when you need root permissions and `sudo` doesn't work.